# How to substract the value of inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell how to substract the OBJ value by 1 ? 
For example the value of "+nmx[n]['id']+" is 2, i want to change it to 1. But, inside the bracket. Thanks.

```
onclick='gogo("+nmx[n]['id']+",1)'

function gogo(obj,xx) {

        $("#service-one").removeClass("active in");
        $("#service-two").addClass("active in");
        $("#lione").removeClass("active");
        $("#litwo").addClass("active");



        if (xx==1)
            var nm = ori;
        else
            var nm = curlist;

        var xpk = obj;

        $("#qcom").attr("src", "img/"+nm[xpk]['company']+".png");
        $("#qmak").val(nm[xpk]['makers']);
        $("#qmod").val(nm[xpk]['models']);
        $("#qyea").val(nm[xpk]['years']);
        $("#qreg").val(nm[xpk]['region']);
        $("#qbon").val(nm[xpk]['bonus']);
        $("#qins").val(nm[xpk]['insured']);
        $("#qpre").val(nm[xpk]['premium']);
        comp =nm[xpk]['company'];

        npremi = parseFloat(nm[xpk]['premium']);
        nins = parseFloat(nm[xpk]['insured']);
        var nx =0.06*npremi;
        $("#mygst").val(nx.toFixed(2));
        var nxf =nx+parseFloat(npremi);
        $("#curnet").val(nxf.toFixed(2));


    }
```

Comment: the value in onclick is invalid

Comment: Where did you declare the nmx array?